# Ajax HTTP POST method fail on Firefox but work well on Safari and Others Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, safari

My app is based substantially on CRUD operations. All operation work great on Safari and other browsers, but not in Firefox. I can not understand what could be the problem. I'm new on js because I come from obj-c whose environment provides an excellent debugging. When i post data from a form to server, I get a 500 internal server error.

I looked for information everywhere, but the suggested solutions do not work for my case. Any help is largely appreciated.

My code:

```
function save() {
var url;

if (save_method == 'add') {
    alert('Method Add');
    var ids = $('input[name="id"]').val();
    var disciplinaNome = $('[name="disciplinaNome"]').val();
    console.log(ids + disciplinaNome);

    url = "http://SERVER.me/Api/v5/create/discipline";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: "disciplinaNome=" + disciplinaNome,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",

        success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            $('#modal_form').modal('hide');

            alert("data saved")
            console.log("Data: " + responseData + "\nStatus: " + textStatus);
            //if success close modal and reload ajax table
            $('#example').dataTable().fnClearTable();
            $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error adding data');
            }
      });

} else {
    url = "http://server/Api/v5/update/discipline";
    alert('Method update');
   }

   $('[name="disciplinaNome"]').val());

   var ids = $('input[name="id"]').val();
   var disciplinaNome = $('[name="disciplinaNome"]').val();
   console.log(ids + disciplinaNome);

   var ajaxLock = 1; 
// ajax adding data to database

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: "id=" + ids + "&disciplinaNome=" + disciplinaNome,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",

    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert("data edited")
        console.log("Data: " + responseData + "\nStatus: " + textStatus);
        //if success close modal and reload ajax table
        $('#modal_form').modal('hide');

        $('#example').dataTable().fnClearTable();

        $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();
        // reload_table();
        ajaxLock = 0;

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        alert('Error update data');
    }
});
}
```

[image]

[image]

UPDATE with disciplinaNome

Comment: Internal Server Errors are **server errors**, while it is probably related to the data you are sending, you need to look at the *server's* error reporting to find out what the problem actually is.

Comment: that's a server error - however the log shows disciplinaN**o**me ... why would firefox arbitrarily change Name to Nome

Comment: That suggests that the code in the question isn't the same code that was running when the screenshots were taken

Comment: Thank you you all, the correct was disciplinaNome. i have edited for international understanting. so consider disciplinaName as disciplinaNome.
The question is why with FF i get 500 error and with other browser i get 200 seccess?

Comment: How does the post show two values being submitted, but the data parameter only has one?

Comment: hi epascarello, if you look the second shot notice that the verb is update, and two parameter was passed: 'id' and 'disciplinaNome'. The last shot show what in ff consolle happen. The first shot, instead, indicated a correct json format. So i start to believe that ff fight with form submit action. I really can't understan why in four browser all goes well and in ff fail. This is understandable for me.